# Why is Chrome debugger Responsive width different from my window.innerWidth?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

So I want to know my screen dimensions and do something to it, here is what I do.

From the Chrome browser "debugger responsive view" I got:

[image]

From my code (this is React, it is just adding an event listener to handle resize):

```js
  function getWindowDimensions() {
    const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window;
    return {
      width,
      height,
    };
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions());
    }
    handleResize();
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []);
```

console log:
[image]

At this point, I am confused. Why is the debugger telling me the width is `767x1160` while the console tells me `window.innerWidth` is `1190x1800`? They are missing out by miles, Why?

P.S. By the look of my page output, the visual looks like `Chrome 767x1160` is correct. So, I **guess** I am using the `window.innerWidth` incorrectly?